# React - 'reject' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I have been working with Node.js to extract some data from my MongoDB server using async await. The code has been working in the Node environment, in which I have been outputting query results to the console. I am now at the point of migrating the code to React for some visualization. But when I move the node I get the error 'reject' is not defined. I might be doing a basic mistake, perhaps I need to import a module?

```
  async componentWillMount(){
    var result = await this.getMongoData("mydb", url);
  }

  getMongoData(dboArg, urlArg) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      MongoClient.connect(urlArg, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(dboArg);
        dbo.collection(myCollection).find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
          db.close();
          err 
              ? reject(err) 
              : resolve(data);
        });
      })
    })  
  }
```

Comment: I see that the question has been marked as off-topic. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have reject as a parameter in your promise.

Learn more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
async componentWillMount(){
  var result = await this.getMongoData("mydb", url);
}

getMongoData(dboArg, urlArg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(urlArg, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(dboArg);
      dbo.collection(myCollection).find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
        db.close();
        err 
            ? reject(err) 
            : resolve(data);
      });
    })
  })  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the reject handler as a parameter to your promise function like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> { 
       // do stuff
})
```